# Using Boruta for determining the magnitude of importance of R, F and M

Tags: r

I am a novice to R and sorry if this question is missing the mark.

I am working on a dataset with high seasonality and trying to assign weights to recency, frequency, and monetary value. For this, I am using the Boruta library in R. Based on the weights of R, F and M I am computing clusters using K-means clustering

1. My data set is from 2017-19 transaction data.
2. I am isolating customers from a year ago and computing how much revenue they generated in 2019
3. From my data set of customers of 2018 and before who made a purchase in 2019, with 'how much they spent in 2019' as the target variable, I am using Boruta.
4. Basis the weights of R, F, and M I am multiplying my columns and computing K-mean clusters

Questions: 1. I understand Boruta is done when there are multiple features - can I use it to compute the weights of R, F, and M? Is there a better way?
2. Is this a good approach to assigning weights to R, F, and M and computing the clusters
3. Is it normal for Boruta to give different outputs every time I run it?
3. Should I ignore recency in my RFM analysis because Boruta is indicating that?

Comment: What you are trying to perform is rather unclear. From step 3 you seems to want to predict purchase made in 2019, right ? your explanatory variables are F, R and M, right ? What model do you want to use ?